# How can I support localization with .po/.mo files in my own applications?

Tags: php, localization

I've dabbled with WordPress for a few years and I notice some plugins have the advanced feature of translating to foreign languages painlessly using .po/.mo files. This is an excellent feature for any application and not just PHP/WordPress.

How can a developer implement a fully translatable application using these files?

Comment: You are probably looking for the [`gettext`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) utility or similar. There are [bindings for PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) (and probably almost any language out there).

Answer (score 0):

User Bakuriu answered this question. GNU's [gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#gettext) open translation utility has bindings for multiple languages and does exactly what I described in the original post.